# Hosting windows add-in in wpf application

Tags: wpf, windows, add-in

We have a windows add-in called DataStream Charting which can be used as add-in in Microsoft word that is a windows application as in the below image:

[image: Add in]

How to host the same windows add-in in Wpf application just as in the Microsoft word. Is this possible and if yes then Kindly Suggest?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, however it would be a ton of work, you would need to emulate **all of MS Word's com add-in architecture**.  Or, at a minimum, the parts of the architecture that the add-in requires (if you can specifically identify those pieces).

It would be a lot of work, so I would not say it's realistically feasible.